# Probability - Weeks and lottery

Tags: probability

> If there is a lottery every week and the chances of winning are $0.07$. Daniel decided to buy a lottery ticket every week till he will win or till he will buy $6$ tickets. $X$ is the number of weeks in which Daniel bought a lottery ticket. What are the chances that $X$ is an even number?

I am not sure how to start. I thought to do $0.07$ by the power of $1$ and then by the power of $2$ etc to check the chances to win in every week, but I'm not sure how to check if a week is an even number and to win the lottery. Is it some sort of Bernoulli experiment?

Comment: One way to compute the probability of an event is to decompose it into disjoint outcomes.  In the question, the event $X$ being an even number is the union of $\{X = 2\wedge \mathsf{win}\}$, $\{X = 4\wedge \mathsf{win}\}$, $\{X = 6\wedge \mathsf{win}\}$ and $\{X = 6\wedge \mathsf{lose}\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of days here are limited, so you can calculate the probability for each day extra and then sum them up.

You can split the probability to three cases: losing the 1st day and winning the 2nd day, losing 1st-3rd day and winning the 4th day, loosing 1st-5th day. All these cases are disjoint. Let p be the chance to win ($p=0.07$). What you get is:
$$
(1-p)p + (1-p)^3p + (1-p)^5 = 0.93\cdot0.07 + 0.93^3\cdot0.07+0.93^5 = 0,817093359
$$